# The best way to read large files in PHP?

Tags: php, large-files

I have to read CSV files line by line which can be 10 to 20 Meg. `file()` is useless and I have to find the quickest way.

I have tried with `fgets()`, which runs fine, but I don't know if it reads a small block each time I call it, or if it caches a bigger one and optimize file I/O.
Do I have to try the `fread()` way, parsing EOL by myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ought to be using [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) if possible.

Otherwise, there is always fgets().

Answer (score 2):

stream_get_line is apparently more efficient than fgets for large files.  If you specify a sensible maximum length for the read I don't see any reason why PHP would have to 'read ahead' to read a line in, as you seem to be worrying.

If you want to use CSVs then fgetcsv will return results in a slightly more sensible format.

Answer (score 1):

[`fgets()`](http://www.php.net/fgets) should be perfectly fine for your needs.  Even [`file()`](http://www.php.ney/file) should be ok - 20mb isn't very big unless you're doing this a lot of times concurrently.

Don't forget you can tune `fgets()` with its second parameter.

Comment: A default PHP setup allows for a maximum memory usage of 8 Mb per process. In that case 20Mb is big. (I know you can change that, but there are obvious reasons as to why you wouldn't want to).

Comment: Jasper Bekkers is right, and file() use too much memory for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `fgetcsv()`, it automatically parses the coma seperated line into an array.

As for the runtime efficiency, I have no idea. You will have to run a quick test, preferably with a file of the size you are expecting to handle later on. But I would be surprised if the fget??? and fput??? functions were not I/O optimised.